# I need to change a color for an accordion I'm working with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion_links

^^^ This is the link to what I need changed.  Specifically, when you activate the accordion, there are 3 links inside.  I want to change the color of the "hover" on the "links" but, cannot figure out how to do it.  I can change the color of  both the button background and the link background.

However, the "light-grey" hover affect is driving me crazy.  Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

simply add this code before body (`!important` forces the element to take this style!)

```
<style>
    a:hover{background-color: green!important;}
</style>
```

or you can make yor own stylesheet and include it after the w3 stylesheet in the `html` before `body` tag (it is good practice to use a `head` tag)..you wount need the `!important` part if you include your own stylesheet after the original one because the repeated styles are being overwriten.

style.css:

```
a:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="w3-container">
     <h2>Accordions</h2>
     <p>An accordion with links:</p>

     <div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey">
        <button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
         Accordion 1
        </button>
    <div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction('Demo2')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
      Accordion 2
    </button>
    <div id="Demo2" class="w3-accordion-content">
      <a class="w3-padding-16" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="w3-padding-16" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="w3-padding-16" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and if you are interested you can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) docoment for some more cool functionality using css selectors

Answer (score 0):

I recommend loading your own css file after the one you have in the example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycssfileurl">
```

In that you should be able to override it like

```
#Demo1 a:hover {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! I messed with both ideas and they worked!